# Dynamically creating checkboxes from an array and then iterate through them to check for selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have been creating a list of checkboxes from returned information from a webservice. The checkboxes render as expected but when I try and then read them to check if they have been selected the code cannot find them.

I have created a panel called `planList` and had the code loop creating the dynamic list of boxes - then on a button being pressed it should iterate through the list of checkboxes to see if the user has selected any values. The code doesn't seem to be picking up any checkboxes unless created dynamically. Anyone able to assist? At the moment I am just trying to pull out the ID if it picks up a checkbox

Code:

```
planList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h2>Plan List </h2>"));
foreach (string[] ar in ws.planS(this.txtGetDetails.Text)) {
    CheckBox cb =  new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = ar[1].ToString();
    cb.ID = ar[0];                
    planList.Controls.Add(cb);                
    planList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b>   Application ID: " + ar[2] + "</b>"));                
    planList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
}

protected void Uploadbutton_Click1(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    foreach (Control c in planList.Controls) {
        CheckBox chx = c as CheckBox;
        if (chx != null) {
            var planid = c.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you adding the checkboxes?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the `CreateChildControls` method and add the checkboxes there. With this, you are creating the controls tree before loading the ViewState, which contains the data of which one was checked.

Comment: thanks 

I was adding them after the page load - have added them into the page load and can now read them.